# extract out text in each line and put it in seperate variables with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following address which is in a paragraph with no great way to select the individual text areas within. I do not have access to this code. I want to extract out each line and put the text values in a variable for each type. Not sure what would be the best way to do it.

Use `.split('<br>')` ? 
then use `.split('&nbsp;')` to separate the state from the zip
same with city and state
I am a little lost here.

Here are the variables I would like.

company name,
person's name,
address1,
city,
state,
country,
zip code,
phone,

Here is the paragraph that i have. I do not need the '(Residential Address)'

```
<p>
XYZ Inc<br>
John&nbsp;Smith<br>
555 Anywhere Street<br>
New York, NY&nbsp;11150<br>
United States<br>
212-555-1212<br>

 (Residential Address)


</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what actually worked with the help of your code JC. I needed to change the second split to split against &nbsp instead of " " and I trimmed all the variables even though some don't really need to.

```
var shipping_info=$('p').html();
var str=shipping_info.split('<br>');
var companyName=jQuery.trim(str[0]);
var personName=jQuery.trim(str[1]).replace('&nbsp;',' ');
var address1=jQuery.trim(str[2]);
var location1=str[3].split(',');
var city=jQuery.trim(location1[0]);
var location1=location1[1].split('&nbsp;');
var state=jQuery.trim(location1[0]);
var zip=jQuery.trim(location1[1]);
var country=jQuery.trim(str[4]);
var phone=jQuery.trim(str[5]);
alert(companyName);
alert(personName);
alert(address1);
alert(city);
alert(state);
alert(zip);
alert(country);
alert(phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a string variable `str` containing your data:

```
var str=str.split("<br>"),
companyName=str[0],
personName=str[1],
address1=str[2],
location=str[3].split(","),
city=location[0],
location=location[1].split(" "),
state=location[0],
zip=location[1],
country=str[4],
phone=str[5];
```

If you give your `<p>` an id: `<p id="values">`, you can do this:

```
var str=document.getElementById("values").innerHTML;
```

Comment: I thing this is almost ok but the br does not separate the city - state or the state - zip, but it is a start!!!

Comment: @user##### you can again use "," to split the strings to retreive city,state and zip string obtained through splitting on "<br>

Comment: I've edited it, it should work assuming the city/state/zip is `City, State Zip`

Comment: If you need to trim your stuff, here's your helper function: `function trim(x) { return x.replace(/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*$/, '$1'); }`. :)

Comment: still checking it, few things though, replace all "," with ";" and you cannot use location as the variable name at least I could not, probably have some conflict with windows.location. I changed it to location1 and it worked then

Comment: Why do you need to replace all "," with ";"? If you do, then place `var` at the start of each line.